# HMS: Getting error in push notification token with error code 907135003

Tags: android, flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I'm new to flutter, Unable to get the token from Huawei push notification in flutter.

I'm using below code to get data:

```
await Push.getToken("");

await initTokenStream();
```

Unable to get the token from huawei push notification in flutter. Getting error in push notification token with error code 907135003

**Log**

```
E/HMSSDK_HmsInstanceId( 5742): TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 907135003 D/HMSLogger( 5742): singleEventMap -> {apiName=getToken, package=com.bghuawei.app, cpAppVersion=1.0.0, version=5.3.0.304, platform=Flutter, result=907135003, costTime=218, service=Cross-Platform, kit=Push, appid=105282649, model=OP4F2F, networkType=WIFI, callTime=1641433679625} I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient( 5742): Enter disconnect, Connection Status: 5
```

Can any one help me !! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the URLs below for the error code description and solution. Please try to use the latest version of HMS Core per Shirley's comment above as well.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/error-code-0000001050255690

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/error-code-0000001050994177

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> error code 907135003

This error is reported when the HMS Core version is too early and needs to be upgraded. Therefore, pls try to upgrade the HMS Core apk to the latest version.