# Huawei HMS core: get token failed, com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135003: client api invalid

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am facing get token failed, com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135003: client api invalid

Comment: Similar question kindly check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71508396/13329100

Answer (score 2):

The resultCode : 907135003 occurs when HMS core is not installed or the version used is too low.

1. If it is non-Huawei device, please install updated version of HMS core in it and try again. Please download latest version from below link:

https://www.huaweicentral.com/download-the-latest-hms-core-apk-19/

2. If it is Huawei device, open the application market, search of HMS Core and Update it.

Please find Screenshot:

If above mentioned steps did not work please follow steps to fix the HMS core cache issue:

(1) Check whether the mobile phone network can access the Internet normally
(2) Reconnect
(3) Please clear the hms core cache (find settings-application-application settings-search for hms core, clean the cache or update to the latest version and try again.)
(4) Uninstall the application and reinstall it and try again.